# total = total + ActiveCell.Value not working in a for each loop

Tags: performance, excel, vba, for-loop, foreach

I have this code where I want to look up some cells in another sheet, and if they match the criteria then add a neighboring cell to the total which is returned to the cell function is called from.

```
Function collectUtfall(A1 As String, Ax As String)
Dim rng As Range
Dim total As Long: total = 0

Set rng = Sheets("Utfall").Range("M2:O272")

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng
    If StrComp(cell.Offset(0, 1).Text, Ax, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        total = total + ActiveCell.Value
    Else

    End If
Next

collectUtfall = total

End Function
```

Problem is that I get a "Circle reference" error when executing. Is there a problem in using `ActiveCell.Value` in that way?

If I just try with a value, say 10, it works just fine:

```
total = total + 10
```

So the problem has to be with the `ActiveCell.Value`?

Comment: You shouldn't use this function with `ActiveCell` as the ActiveCell is always the cell you are typing in this function.

Comment: Use total = total + cell.Value

Comment: Yes, thank you that was an easy fix!

Comment: There are some additional problems with your UDF which I would recommend you fix - 1) your function as coded needs to be made volatile since it refers to cells that are not in the UDF arguments. 2) referring to cell.Text is dangerous since the cell referred to may return #### etc 3) you don't need OFFSET, just change the "M2:O272" to "O2:P272"

Comment: @CharlesWilliams Cell.Text is fine as long as you know your intentions to use it and how it works. Why O2:P272? Offset is a better option here when iterating over one column. There is no point in comparing two columns against the same value while adding the sum (*numerical*) which is one of the columns. Please see my answer if I am being unclear.

Comment: @mehow : there are very few reasons to ever use .TEXT: see http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/  99.9% of the time users are better off avoiding .Text and I do not see anything in the OPs post to justify it

Answer (score 0):

```
Function collectUtfall(A1 As String, Ax As String)

Dim rng As Range

Dim total As Long


set total = 0


Set rng = Sheets("Utfall").Range("M2:O272")


Dim cell As Range


For Each cell In rng

    If StrComp(cell.Offset(0, 1).Text, Ax, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        total = total + Cell.Value

    Else


    End If

Next Cell


collectUtfall = total


End Function
```